# Вывести последнюю запись

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 3 таблицы:
**users**

```
mess_dialog

dialog_id | dialog_user_first | dialog_user_second|
         1|                  1|                  9|






messages

mess_id | mess_sender_id | mess_reciver_id | message | mess_read |
       1|               9|                1|   hello |         1 |
       2|               9|                1|first msg|         0 |
       3|               9|                1|last msg |         0 |
```

И сам запрос

```sql
SELECT * //тут не стал перечислять 
      FROM users 
      INNER  JOIN mess_dialog ON mess_dialog.dialog_user_first = :userId1 
      AND users.user_id = mess_dialog.dialog_user_second

      INNER JOIN messages ON messages.mess_reciver_id = :reciveId
      AND messages.mess_sender_id = mess_dialog.dialog_user_second
      AND messages.mess_read = 0

      GROUP BY mess_dialog.dialog_id DESC
      ORDER BY messages.mess_id DESC
```

Запрос который выводит диалоги пользователя и последнее сообщение из таблицы messages где read = 0.
Проблема в том, что выводится не последняя а первая запись где read = 0 .
[ссылка на: sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08f384/1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Укажите точно версию своего сервера. Хотя для показанного текста запроса (RTFM "SQL Mode" -> only_full_group_by) в любом случае будет выводиться случайное (не первое, не последнее, а именно случайное) значение из группы.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users 
  INNER  JOIN mess_dialog ON mess_dialog.dialog_user_first = 1
  AND users.user_id = mess_dialog.dialog_user_second

  INNER JOIN messages ON messages.mess_reciver_id = 1
  AND messages.mess_sender_id = mess_dialog.dialog_user_second
  AND messages.mess_read = 0

  ORDER BY messages.mess_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогает, так как если  диалогов будет много то будет показан только 1. Но спасибо за ответ.

Comment: тогда вопрос не ясен